# Failed to Process, Error while dexing, when trying to run on Android

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, dex

The application that I am working on compiles just fine when I hit either Build > Clean Project, or Build > Build Project.  It is when I select to Run it that I get the following error message:

> Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /Users//Documents/Work-Related/Repositories///build/intermediates/transforms/instantRunSlicer/boost/debug/0
>
> Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing /$.class
>
> Error:com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: local 000d: invalid
>   Error:Execution failed for task '::transformClassesWithDexBuilderForBoostDebug'.
>
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: 
>   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /Users//Documents/Work-Related/Repositories///build/intermediates/transforms/instantRunSlicer/boost/debug/0

Other messages here have to do with merging after the Dex, but this dex fails as a whole.

The main question/issue would be what could possibly cause this, or what could be looked for when trying to resolve this issue?

(Unable to post code due to proprietary nature of the application.  Error messages have been edited due to the same.>

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this question to hopefully provide some assistance to others that might be running into this same problem.

I was unable to locate any answer to my question, so I reverted to the most recent successful submission for the branch I was working on, and re-did all of the work one step at a time to see where in the process it broke.

I located the issue, and it relates to an annotation of @NonNull on an overridden method.

Lint provided the error: "Not annotated parameter overrides @ParametersAreNonnullbyDefault parameter message.  To resolve this issue I put @NonNull before the item in question.

Lint was happy and no longer gave me an error, but the Dexing system failed at that point.

I will need to continue working on how to resolve the Lint error without having this same error occur again, but wanted to provide this option for others to look at if they receive the same error message.